# How to get "previous" node in ANTLR ParseTree

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have the following rule: `regExp : branch (PIPE branch)*`. I built a listener and on my `exitBranch` method I want to know if a `branch` comes after a `PIPE` token. Something like

```java
@Override
public void exitBranch(BranchContext ctx)
{
    if (/*branch is preceeded by PIPE)*/)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

In case it helps, here's an example of a parse tree (`PIPE` corresponds to the `|` token):

```
regExp
  branch
    piece
      atom a
  |
  branch
    piece
      atom b
<EOF>
```

Edit: I guess I could check if a `branch` is the first child of `regExp` but I would like a better solution

Comment: There is no referential value for the index of the child into the children array of the parse node. You'll have to write a method to find the node in the parent's children list, convert to index, then back up.

Answer (score 1):

If you break

```
regExp : branch (PIPE branch)*;
```

Into something like:

```
regExp : branch pipeBranch*;
pipeBranch: PIPE branch;
```

You would get a specific context for `pipeBranch` and could set a listener for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `ctx.PIPE().size() > 0`. If that's the case you know you must have a branch preceded by a PIPE.